# Javascript condition optimization

Tags: javascript

Can the following condition be optimized/simplified ?

```
if (!this.properties.width || 
    this.properties.width <= 0 || 
    !this.properties.height || 
    this.properties.height <= 0)
  return;
```

So basically if properties does not have a width or height property or the width or height property is less than or equal to zero then return

Comment: Signatures are discouraged in the complete stackexchange Network. For more information you might want to read [this meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274366/informal-language-and-moderation/274369#274369)

Comment: What values exactly do you expect here? `undefined` for non-existing properties, integers otherwise? Do width and height actually ever become negative?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd simply flip it around:

```
if( !(this.properties.width > 0 && this.properties.height > 0) ) {
  return;
}
```

This will catch `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, etc., etc.. It will allow numeric strings (provided they can be coerced to a number greater than zero), and of course it'll allow straight-up positive, non-zero numbers.

---

*Update:* There's one edge-case I've come across: Arrays. It's some unfortunate JavaScript weirdness to do with type coercion:

```
[] > 0;     // => false (so far so good)
[0] > 0;    // => false (as it should be)
[1] > 0;    // => true  (what?)
[1, 1] > 0; // => false (WHAT?)
```

So an array with just a single numeric element will be treated as a number when comparing.

Well, actually, as far as I can tell, the array is coerced to a string by coercing each element to a string, and joining them with a comma, and the joined string is then <strike>compared lexicographically</strike> coerced to a number in order to be compared. (Thanks to Robert in the comments for the correction)

```
[1] + 0;    // => "10"
[1, 1] + 0; // => "1,10"
"0" > 0;    // => false
"1" > 0;    // => true
"1,1" > 0;  // => false
```

I love JavaScript, but sometimes... jeez...

Comment: It's also worth noting that you can get a little performance boost by not performing two scope lookups on `this.properties` by caching `var props = this.properties;` and then just accessing as `props.width` and `props.height`in your logic

Comment: It doesn't compare lexicographically. Instead the resulting string gets coerced to a number. But since numbers don't contain commas `+'1,1'` is `NaN`.

Comment: @Robert Ah, right. Thanks for clearing that up; I'll note it in the answer

Answer (score 8):

While `!this.properties.width` tests if the value is `undefined` (i.e. it does not exist) it does not tell someone who comes along to maintain it later that that was your intention.

You could write:

```
if (
     this.properties.width === undefined
  || this.properties.width <= 0
  || this.properties.height === undefined
  || this.properties.height <= 0
)
{
  return;
}
```

or if the intention is to exit the function early if width or height is not a number then you could use:

```
if (
     isNaN( this.properties.width )
  || this.properties.width <= 0
  || isNaN( this.properties.height )
  || this.properties.height <= 0
)
{
  return;
}
```

**DRYNESS**

If the same test is going to be repeated for many properties or repeatedly throughout the code then you could wrap it in an appropriately function:

```
function isPositiveNonZeroNumber( value )
{
    return !isNaN( value ) && value > 0;
}
```

then you can write:

```
if (
     !isPositiveNonZeroNumber( this.properties.width )
  || !isPositiveNonZeroNumber( this.properties.height )
)
{
  return;
}
```